# Please undelete my answer

Tags: discussion

I wrote an answer to this question: [Software to sync with tempo in violin](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/123234/19678)

It was deleted.  There were two comments:

> This looks like a product advertisement. The main claim (that one should not use a metronome for several first years of practice) is not supported by any arguments.

> while you may prefer the Suzuki method, your post doesn't answer the OP at all.

I started playing the cello at the age of 8.  I did not start with the Suzuki method.  I remember the feeling OP described:

> thinking about everything makes me lose tempo

Both my children started with the Suzuki method, and I found it to be well structured, such that the student doesn't often have that overwhelming feeling of trying to remember three or more things to do differently, all at the same time.

I recommended that OP switch to the Suzuki method not as an advertisement, but as a suggestion to help OP.

As to whether my post answered the question, I think it did.  In the Suzuki method, rhythms are worked on in a structured way, through imitation, and the student learns to produce rhythms at a consistent tempo in a similar way to how a child learns language.

It should be possible to write positive things about a pedagogic method, with an explanation of why one thinks the method would help OP solve their problem, without the post getting deleted.

Comment: A suggestion for how to modify the currently closed post: Rather than focus on the Suzuki method itself, describe how to practice and then mention that that method of practice is built into the Suzuki approach. That focuses the answer directly on the question of "how" and then only indirectly "promotes" the Suzuki method.

Comment: The question explicitly asks for "software to sync with tempo" - and your post is literally a frame challenge. Please do not do that.

Comment: @DoktorMayhem - Is a frame challenge permitted when it is explicitly introduced?  If not, must it be deleted, or can it be left in place, perhaps to be downvoted?

Comment: @aparente001 Not a mod, but my best understanding is that frame challenges are okay as long as there is first an answer to the given question. I think my earlier comment addresses that should you choose to take me up on the suggestion.

Comment: @DoktorMayhem Please see my previous comment. I don't want to mistakenly lead aparente001 astray or create an inadvertent conflict.

Comment: @DoktorMayhem - I reworked the post per Aaron's suggestion.  I hope you will undelete it now.

Comment: @Aaron  - thanks, I think my answer benefitted a lot from the reworking.

Comment: I think you're headed in the right direction, but, IMO, it's still much too focused on the Suzuki method itself. Just one example: in your point #2, you could just say "practice rhythms in isolation, or in very simple contexts, so there are fewer other details to pay attention to." The technique stands on its own even without attaching it to a particular teaching method. At the end of the post you can then say "these tips and exercises are ideas I've gleaned from the Suzuki method. It has been effective for my kids and me, so you might look into it."

Comment: You are still focusing on an outcome the OP hasn't asked for. Look at the top two answers - they perfectly describe solutions for what the OP asked for. You avoid that question entirely and effectively tell the OP not to use a metronome.

Comment: @DoktorMayhem - I also suggested ways of getting a tempo connected to the bow arm, and said that choosing a slower tempo can help.

Comment: This is over-policing.  Let the OP decide whether it was useful.